# Enviar un URL con Id como parametro con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, url, knockoutjs

Tengo en una lista que muestro a traves de KO, algunos objetos. Necesito que al seleccionar alguno, me seleccione el ID y lo envíe junto al URL. Me dan una mano?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script> var url = "http://miurl/Atributo/Index?Id";  </script>

<div class="col s12">
            <div class="collection">
                <!--ko foreach: atributo-->
                <a href="javascript: window.open(url)" target="_parent" class="collection-item">
                    <span data-bind="text: nombreAtributo" class="center"></span>
                </a>
                <!--/ko-->
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Quita el campo Id de la definición de la URL, ya que lo podrías bindear directamente en el link de este modo:

```
<a data-bind="attr: { href: '?id=' + $data.id}"></a>
```

Por tanto, quedaría:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script> var url = "http://miurl/Atributo/Index";  </script>

<div class="col s12">
    <div class="collection">
        <!--ko foreach: atributo-->
        <a href="javascript: window.open(url)" target="_parent" class="collection-item">
            <span data-bind="attr: {href: '?id=' + $data.id, text: nombreAtributo}" class="center"></span>
        </a>
        <!--/ko-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias Ferran!

Comment: se llega a armar bien el URL con el id como parametro. Pero no se si no llega bien, o si no lo estoy pudiendo extraer en la nueva ventana donde lo necesito. 
La funcionalidad es la siguiente: 
Con ese Id que envío en la url, debo mostrar el atributo al que pertenece. Y cuando se muestra la nueva ventana, me dice id=undefined.